# Does mixing memory with and without heat shields work?

Tags: memory

A friend gave me some of his spare memory to increase the memory in my PC.  I now have 16 GB instead of 8 GB.

The PC boots, but the memory he gave me had heat shields on, whereas mine does not.

Is this ok?  Will my PC work, or will it have problems?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the heatshield, but are the speeds, timings, and specs the same?

Comment: Most memory do not have heat shields

Comment: To a large extent heat *spreaders* (not heat shields) arn't really essential. They're either for higher frequency/ "overclocked" ram or cosmetics.

Comment: And _Heat Spreaders_ are really joyful when they pop loose causing the chips to not be able to shed heat through normal airflow. That wonderful eye candy is now the reason your computer is crashing. Pull the memory boards and inspect the heat spreaders every so often, if you see a gap where they're trying to separate from the chips, throw out the board unless you can finish out the delamination without destroying the chips and remove them to extend its life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it has the right number of pins, yes. There's no real side effect of heat shields in most systems, so it doesn't really matter. However, do be aware about mixing different *speeds*, *timings*, and *ECC*.

You may put it in only to discover that your computer beeps about three times and won't turn on (configuration mismatch). Or, you may notice that despite the increase in RAM, your system runs *slower* (speed mismatch). Or, in some rare cases, you might find that your motherboard actually doesn't support more than 8GB of memory, or fails to boot because the RAM is outside of the system's operating speed ranges (BIOS/memory controller limitations).

None of these situations are permanent and shouldn't be fatal to your hardware, but I would strongly suggest consulting your motherboard's manual (or the manufacturer's spec sheets for laptops) before you waste your time installing something that won't work or will have an overall negative system performance.

It should only take a couple of minutes with a manual to see the limits on memory, speed, etc with regards to RAM, and if you have no idea what the RAM itself is, there's usually an identifying part number sticker you can Google to determine if it's within the system's specifications.

Comment: Yup. These are the *important* things. Bit of pretty aluminium, less so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use memory modules with or without heat spreaders or both at the same time.  It is best to use memory modules of the same type when possible.  They should have the same capacity, frequency and timings preferably.  You can use different capacity, frequency and timings if they are compatible with the motherboard but the frequency and timings will be automatically set to the slowest module(s.)  If you use different capacities you will be running in Flex Mode rather than Dual Channel Mode.  Dual Channel Mode offers the most performance.  You should use memory modules that are validated to work by the motherboard manufacturer, check their website QVL (Qualified Vendor's List.)